# How to unmerge a Git merge?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-pull

I accidentally did a `git pull origin master` from dev, and master got merged into dev.
Is it possible to unmerge?

I've already seen different solutions, i tried this one from both dev and master :
`git revert -m 1 <commit>` (once each)
But i got : Everything is up-to-date, each time

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can reset your branch to the state it was in just before the merge if you find the commit it was on then.

One way is to use `git reflog`, it will list all the HEADs you've had.
I find that `git reflog --relative-date` is very useful as it shows how long ago each change happened.

Once you find that commit just do a `git reset --hard <commit id>` and your branch will be as it was before.

If you have **SourceTree**, you can look up the `<commit id>` there if `git reflog` is too overwhelming.

Comment: Since it's an odd merge : "pull origin master: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy" i'm a bit lost. Would you advise me to do a git reset --hard 757501b from master (even though there is no changes in history). Or git reset --hard 14cbb9c from dev ?

Comment: It's dev you need to fix, right? So find the commit that was made on dev just before this bad merge and do the reset on dev to that commit.

Comment: git revert -m 1 <commit id>

Comment: Worst noting that if you pushed a merge commit, then NOT apply this approach, as that will mess up one's master branch who pulled it. Prefer revert instead.

Comment: type :q to exit vim after reflog

Answer (score 96):

If you haven't committed the merge, then use:

`git merge --abort`

Comment: Thanks it worked because I have yet to commit the merge :)

Comment: @Eightgate, he has mentioned explicitly "If you haven't committed the merge, then use: git merge --abort"

Comment: This will work if you haven't committed the merge, cheers.

Answer (score 15):

If the merge has been accepted accidentally by `git merge --continue` or if the changes are auto committed when `git pull <branch>`, then we can revert or undo the very recent merge by executing

```
git reset --merge HEAD~1
```

> This command reverts our repository to the last commit. HEAD refers to the current state of your repository; HEAD~1 is the last commit in your repository.

Answer (score 7):

`git revert -m` allows to un-merge still keeping the history of both merge and un-do operation. Might be good for documenting probably.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a history merge.
First to find the merge commit id using git log like this:

```
 git log --after="2022-09-29 00:00:00" --before="2022-09-30 23:00:00"
```

This will show the log in 2022-09-29 (suppose the merge happened in 2022-09-29)

Then find the commit id, and run:

```
git revert -m 1 <commit id>
```